# Radio buttons generated with rails radio_button not changing when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, onclick, onchange

I have the following code in `categories.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@marker) do |f| %>
  <div> <%= f.radio_button("category", "1") %><label>Category 1</label> </div>
  <div> <%= f.radio_button("category", "2") %><label>Category 2</label> </div>
  <div> <%= f.radio_button("category", "3") %><label>Category 3</label> </div>
<% end %>
```

and the following javascript code in `categories.js`:

```
var update = function() {
  return console.log("Category Selected");
};

$("input[type='radio']").change(update);
```

The radio buttons never seem to get changed (nothing shows on my console log when I click a radio button).

What I originally want to do is to have a `subcategory div` inside every category one that will only show when the respective radio button is selected (and hide when another button is clicked).

**UPDATE:** I got this working with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
      $(".subcategory").hide();
      $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

Not sure why I had to put the code inside `.ready` though, to be honest. :$

Comment: The reason is your change event handler is loaded before the html elements are loaded.   You can simply add the script at the end of the body too..

Comment: @Praveen But if I want to have the js code in another file I have to put it inside `.ready`?

Comment: No issues. You can simply add the `<script src="file name" />` at the end of the body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    $(".subcategory").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```